# error while fetching data from firebase push notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to react native and I'm working on firebase push notification. I'm getting the notification, but the problem is I'm not able to fetch data and display it in flatlist. Notification are shown perfectly. But the problem is why I can't fetch data. I want this event data to be fteched in my notification list which i have added below image.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const firebase = require("firebase");
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(db);
    }
    this.fetchEventsList()
}
// Fetch events list
fetchEventsList = () => {
    Preference.set('userPhoneCheck', '+917508060520');
    let phone = Preference.get('userPhoneCheck');

    firebase.database().ref('/users').child(phone).child('/events').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        let items = Object.values(data);
        this.setState({
            userEventsList: items
        });
        // this.deleteOldEvents();
        this.initAllEventList();
    }).then((data) => {}).catch((error) => {
        //error callback
        console.log('error ', error)
    })
}


//fetch the friends list according to group name
initAllEventList = () => {
    //let groupName='G1';
    let eventId = '';
    let userEventsList = [...this.state.userEventsList];
    for (var i = 0; i < userEventsList.length; i++) {
        eventId = userEventsList[i].eventId;
        ToastAndroid.show("eventId>" + eventId, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        if (eventId != '') {
            this.fetchFriendsList(eventId);
        }
    }
}
//app users remove that not in contacts
fetchFriendsList = (eventId) => {
    let allEventsList = [...this.state.allEventsList];
    firebase.database().ref('/events').child(eventId).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        let items = Object.values(data);

        allEventsList.push(items);
        this.setState({
            allEventsList: allEventsList
        });

        ToastAndroid.show("kk>" + allEventsList.length, ToastAndroid.SHORT);

    }).then((data) => {

    }).catch((error) => {
        //error callback
        console.log('error ', error)
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: When you run this code, which precise piece of it doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm getting notification but the problem is when i'm trying to fetch data i'm not getting it. i just want the events to be shown.

Comment: i want to fetch this event in my notification list.

Comment: i have added image in above plzz see it

Comment: what does simply calling firebase.database().ref('/events).once('value') give you?

if you're getting the list of events, remove the .child(eventId) because that will get you the data of the event.